# Could not find the correct Provider<UserProvider> above this AddMeal Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I'm trying to use provider inorder to write data onto firestore db but i keep on getting this error-

Could not find the correct Provider above this AddMeal Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.
- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.
- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that AddMeal is under your MultiProvider/Provider.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

  For example, instead of:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
      // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
      child: Text(context.watch<Example>()),
    ),
  }
  ```

  consider using `builder` like so:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
      builder: (context) {
        // No longer throws
        return Text(context.watch<Example>()),
      }
    ),
  }
  ```

here's a snippet of my code where im trying to use the provider below-

```
 class _AddMealState extends State<AddMeal> {
  final TextEditingController _mealNameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _priceController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _mealDescriptionController =
      TextEditingController();

  Uint8List? _file;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final UserProvider userProvider = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 1.0,
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData(
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        title: const Text(
          "Inventory",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 60.0, horizontal: 16.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => _selectImage(context),
                child: Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(),
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  height: 210.0,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: _file == null
                          ? const NetworkImage(
                                  'https://i.stack.imgur.com/l60Hf.png')
                              as ImageProvider
                          : MemoryImage(_file!),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                child: TextFieldInput(
                  maxLines: 1,
                  maxLength: TextField.noMaxLength,
                  controller: _mealNameController,
                  labelText: 'Meal Name',
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                child: TextFieldInput(
                  maxLines: 1,
                  maxLength: TextField.noMaxLength,
                  controller: _priceController,
                  labelText: 'price',
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                child: TextFieldInput(
                  maxLines: 5,
                  controller: _mealDescriptionController,
                  labelText: 'Meal description',
                  maxLength: 150,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 28.0),
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  mealSize(context),
                  const SizedBox(height: 9.0),
                  mealSize(context),
                  const SizedBox(height: 9.0),
                  mealSize(context),
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 40.0),
              GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    addMenu(userProvider.getUser.name);
                  },
                  child: const Button(btnText: "Add Food Item")),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

snippet of Userprovider code-

```
class UserProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  User? _user;

  User get getUser => _user!;

  Future<void> refreshUser() async {
    User user = await AuthController().getUserDetails();
    _user = user;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

*The relevant error-causing widget was
AddMeal-*

```
InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  // splashColor:
                  //Color.fromARGB(255, 143, 140, 140);
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => 
                      const AddMeal()));
                },
                child: const Option(title: "Inventory", icon: Icons.inventory)),
```

Comment: Have you read the error that you pasted here?

Comment: so where they have given me 'use builder' suggestion , should I use it on the Widget that's causing  the relevant error and if so will serve the same purpose as the former code - which is navigation